# How to override Text of label component in jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to change the label text of a jsp page after it is redirected from 
a servlet. I used the below code but it doesn't work :

```
response.sendRedirect("Welcome.jsp?user=Data Stored Successfully");
```

Should I use a Session instead or it can be done in other way?

Actually the static text on label of jsp page is printed everytime.
How do I overwrite the text.

Comment: Why it doesn't work? What is the problem in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you're talking about with "text of label component", so I'll just assume a HTML `<label>` element.

Basically, you can display request parameters in EL as follows:

```
${param.name}
```

This does effectively the same as `out.print(request.getParameter("name"))`. So, if you want to display "text of label component" dynamically with a parameter with the name `user`, then you just need to assign it as such:

```
<label>${param.user}</label>
```